# How do I generate d.ts file types when these errors are preventing it?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript

When attempting to generate TypeDefs for this file (named) globals.ts, I am seeing these errors.  Cannot find name 'DataView', 'Map', 'Set' and 'WeakMap'.  I found 'weakmap' is defined in lib.d.ts, but that's not in my project..

I'm running TS 1.5 [beta], but suspect some other fundamental typedef (missing) issue.  Please advise on where to find proper typedefs.

[image: Given:]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataView`, `Map`, `Set` and `WeakMap` are ES6 classes. The compiler can't find them when you target ES5. You can comment out corresponding lines in `node.d.ts` to get rid of the errors.

Another option would be to compile with `--target ES6`

Comment: I also found reloading node.d.ts (not sure what changed, from before other than I opened this solution in VS2015 (beta))...  I reloaded the Node.d.ts to  Type definitions for Node.js v0.12.0...  Which what I had prior to this goofy foul up.

Comment: I confirmed that the root cause of this was just opening an existing Typescript NODE console project in the new version of VS2015, it automatically will change the typedef files to support the new version of Javascript by default.  If you then go back to VS2013 you have to reload or delete the definitions you don't want.